# Recursive stored procedure that returns a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table with directories. Each directory has a parentid to its parent folder. I need to create a stored procedure or function that takes a directory id, and returns all of its child directories recursive. What is the correct approach to create a recursive function/procedure that returns a single result? The result needs to be common for all the different recursive calls so I guess it cannot be scoped to the single procedure alone? Do you use a temp table, or pass the result set to each procedure call or?

[image]

As Stated this is almost a dublicate of anther thread with the exception of breaking the recursive execution when IsMigrationRoot differs from null. Following worked:

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDirectoriesToMigrate]
(
    @DirId uniqueidentifier
)
AS
            ;WITH CTE AS
            (
                         SELECT [DirectoryId], [ParentId], Name
                         FROM Directories
                         WHERE directoryid=@DirId

```
                     UNION ALL

                     SELECT T1.[DirectoryId], T1.[DirectoryId], T1.Name
                     FROM Directories T1
                     INNER JOIN CTE T2 ON T1.[ParentId] = T2.[DirectoryId] where IsMigrationRoot is null
        )
        SELECT *
        FROM CTE
```

GO

Comment: Sounds like you have hierachies in your set up? AS in a Directory has subdirectories, which may also, have subdirectorys, which may... etc, etc. Have a look at Jeff Moden's [Hierarchies on Steroids](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Hierarchy/94040/). If my understanding is right, should get you on the right path.

Comment: can you add your table structure and some sample data?

Comment: I have added sample table in main question. I cannot use the SQL hierchies because I actually have some logic filtering all childs with migration root from the result.

Comment: So the query should be: "select all childs but not childs where migrationroot=1 and the childs of those".

Comment: All recursive questions in SQL Server are answered the same way - use a recursive cte.